# Delete final positional argument from command in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script called dosmt where I input a couple args and then print something:

```
if [ "${@: -1}" == "--ut" ]; then
    echo "Hi"
fi
```

What I'm trying to do is delete the last positional argument which is `--ut` if the statement is true. So if my input were to be `$ dosmt hello there --ut`, it would echo `Hi`, but if I were to print the args after, I just want to have `hello there`. So basically I'm trying to delete the last argument for good and I tried using shift but that's only temporary so that doesn't work...

Comment: As an aside, using `==` inside `[ ]` is not guaranteed by POSIX to work; the only string comparison operator provided by the standard is `=`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: (As a second aside, the traditional-UNIX approach only allowed options like `--utc` at the *front* of a command, before positional arguments, so they could always be shifted off; allowing them anywhere is something of a GNUism).

Comment: See Guideline 9 and Guideline 10 in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good points re _placement_ of options, but note that POSIX doesn't support "long" options (`--{multi-char-name}`) _at all_.

Comment: @mklement0, indeed, but even GNU tools still honor `--` as an end-of-options sigil. Thus, honoring an option at the end of the list of positional parameters without reference to what precedes it is incompatible with GNU conventions as well as POSIX ones.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Agreed re `--`, but, in practice, GNU utilities _do_ allow mixing options and operands (irrespective of whether the options are "long" or "short"); try `ls * -l` or `ls * --inode`. Conversely: POSIX rules do not  apply to a  utility/script that recognizes something like `--ut` as a valid option.

Comment: @mklement0: `ls * -l` works unless `--` is in use, but to be safe against unexpected behavior in processing filenames starting with dashes, `--` **should** be used by folks writing tools for use by/from robust scripts. Hence, `ls -l -- *` is the Right Thing, and allowing `--` to be used in that way preserves a tool's ability to be called from an adequately paranoid script. Designing a calling convention that prevents best practices from being followed is designing for fail.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Agreed; let me try to summarize: While GNU utilities _allow_ you to freely mix options and operands, it is _good practice_ to place _all_ options _before_ operands and to use `--` to explicitly signal that all remaining arguments should be considered _operands_ (as opposed to options).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let's set the parameters that you want:

```
$ set -- hello there --ut
```

We can verify that the parameters are correct:

```
$ echo "$@"
hello there --ut
```

Now, let's remove the last value:

```
$ set -- "${@: 1: $#-1}"
```

We can verify that the last value was successfully removed:

```
$ echo "$@"
hello there
```

#### Demonstration in a script

To demonstrate this as part of a script:

```
$ cat script
#!/bin/bash
echo Initial values="$@"
set -- "${@: 1: $#-1}"
echo Final values="$@"
```

We can run with your arguments:

```
$ script hello there --ut
Initial values=hello there --ut
Final values=hello there
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Very good and thank you for pointing out the quoting.

Comment: ++; @CharlesDuffy: Re the `"${@:0}"` tangent (from your since-deleted answer): best to stay away from index `0`, not least because the behavior changed between Bash 3.x and 4.x: `set -- foo; echo "${@:0}"` yields just `foo` in Bash 3.x, whereas 4.x (at least as of 4.3.42) yields `{value-of-$0} foo`. Note that neither version includes `$0` if `set` was never called.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! Just to make sure I understand, you're not actually deleting any argument, instead you're saying "Keep everything starting from the arg in position 1 (being `hello`) to the arg in the final position -1 (being `there`)" right?

Comment: No.  Technically, it is replacing all the arguments with the arguments starting from the first and continuing through to the argument __before__ the last argument.  It thereby has the effect of removing the last argument.